# How to take the Max value from a List of object where the same objects exists with many duplicate rows

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects which returned from database, sometimes it may have even 25k to 50k records.

I am grouping them right now with one order to make the group of corresponding items.

But also I need to take the max version of the objects in that list for each grouped list where so many duplicate versions also will be available.

```
public class Items
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class ItemInfo : ReleaseInfo
{
    public virtual IGrouping<int,Items> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

For example,

```
var groupedList = (from cn in ItemList
                               group cn by cn.ProductId into itemGroup
                               orderby itemGroup.Key ascending
                               select new ItemInfo
                               {
                                   cn.ProductId = itemGroup.Key,
                                   ProductName = itemGroup.FirstOrDefault().ProductName,
                                   ItemList= itemGroup
                               });
```

This Itemlist is returned from DB and columns are below,

`ID, Name, ProductName, ProductId and Version`

So now we need to check with same ID and ProductId is there any items duplicated for each groupedList, if then we need to take max value of that using the Version column and keep only that in the list.

**Example dataset:**
**First Grouped List:**

```
**ROW 1** ID - 1, Product ID - 1 Version 1
**ROW 2** ID - 1, Product ID - 1 Version 2
**ROW 3** ID - 1, Product ID - 1 Version 3
```

**Second Grouped List:**

```
**ROW 1** ID - 1, Product ID - 2 Version 1
**ROW 2** ID - 2, Product ID - 2 Version 2
```

from the above data it need to pass `ID-1, product ID- 1, Version 3` from First list and second row from second list to the next steps.

How we can do the group by, If it is one single entity I can do orderbydescending and take the first element but i need to loop through the list of items where other entities also available.

Comment: `If it is one single entity I can do orderbydescending and take the first element but i need to loop through the list of items where other entities also available`, Can you please explain more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving this answer as per my understanding, If I miss anything or miss understood your requirement please comment, I'll update the answer.

Assuming your classes are as below:

```
public class Items
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}

public class ItemInfo
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Items>> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

---

LINQ:

```
List<Items> itemLists = new List<Items>();
var filteredItems = itemLists.Where(x => x.Version == itemLists.Where(y => y.ProductId == x.ProductId).Max(z => z.Version));
var itemsInfo = new ItemInfo { ItemList = filteredItems.GroupBy(x => x.ProductId) };
```

Comment: There is a little different I have updated my question please check. BTW Thanks in advance, I got idea to do but casting fail now so am checking. 

Update : Please check now

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Updated the answer, Modified the `ItemInfo` class. please check that once. Either you can get the IEnumerable<ItemInfo> or as modified @Samaritan_Learner

Comment: Thanks for that, Still i am modifying the conversion i will update the answer. hope you wont mind. Thanks again.